# why data-icon for jquery mobile did not display?

Tags: jquery-mobile

i used data-icon in my code with the button, but the problem is, the icon did not display. it only display a circle..

this is my html code

```
<a href="index.html" data-role="button" data-icon="delete">Remove</a> 
<a href="index.html" data-role="button" data-icon="plus">Add</a> 
<a href="index.html" data-role="button" data-icon="arrow-u">Up</a> 
<a href="index.html" data-role="button" data-icon="arrow-d">Down</a>
```

i'm not why this problem occur, for all button which use icon or automatically have icon like

```
data-add-back-btn="true"
```

the back icon also doesn't display, only the button with the text back

can anyone help me? thanks.

Comment: i m also facing the same problem

Answer (score 3):

Links are not turned into buttons unless you add the `data-role="button"` attribute.

Form `<input type="button" />` and `<input type="submit" />` are automatically turned into "Button Widgets", as are `<button></button>` tags.

Documentation: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.0/docs/buttons/buttons-types.html

Comment: i want to nav bar in footer.. although i copied the same code from the jquerymobile page still the data-icon did not display

    <a href="index.html" data-role="button" data-icon="delete">Remove</a>
    <a href="index.html" data-role="button" data-icon="plus">Add</a>
    <a href="index.html" data-role="button" data-icon="arrow-u">Up</a>
    <a href="index.html" data-role="button" data-icon="arrow-d">Down</a>

Answer (score 3):

You should add 'images' folder (which is coming with jquery mobile folder) within your project. You should add this 'images' folder to the same folder where jquery.mobile.js and jquery.mobile.css files are kept.

I also faced the same problem, after doing so many trial and errors i found this solution..
Now the icons are displaying... :)

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this problem on my iPad.  I have figured out that it is the theme from the roller page that is screwing it up.

If I remove the reference to theme, everything shows up.  The theme doesn't mess things up on the iPad simulator.  It just messes up the iPad.

Edit - To be more specific, it is the most recent theme roller that screws it up.  I created another theme in an older version and the icons showed backup.  I had tried updating my jquery mobile script to the most recent one, but that didn't have an effect one way or another.

Answer (score 0):

Just to add for anyone using jQuery mobile with **Phonegap**, the **images** folder from jQuery mobile should be copied into the **css** folder. The css folder is of course inside the **www** folder.

Hope it helps someone.